# Formatting data using nested d3 and ParseDate function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multidimensional-array, date-formatting

I'm stuck in a infernal loop trying to build a bar chart with x time axis and nested function on my y values axis.

Let's say I have a dataset of 7 days from the 1st of May to the 8 of May.

```
var dataset = [{"strength":1702,"day":"2016-05-01T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":2,"name":"batman"},
{"strength":1703,"day":"2016-05-01T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":4,"name":"batman"},
{"strength":1704,"day":"2016-05-01T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":1,"name":"batman"},
{"strength":1705,"day":"2016-05-02T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":6,"name":"superman"},
{"strength":1706,"day":"2016-05-02T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":8,"name":"superman"},
{"strength":1707,"day":"2016-05-02T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":4,"name":"superman"},
{"strength":1708,"day":"2016-05-03T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":5,"name":"superman"},
{"strength":1709,"day":"2016-05-05T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":1,"name":"ironman"},
{"strength":1710,"day":"2016-05-05T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":12,"name":"ironman"},
{"strength":1711,"day":"2016-05-05T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":9,"name":"ironman"},
{"strength":1712,"day":"2016-05-06T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":1,"name":"ironman"},
{"strength":1713,"day":"2016-05-07T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":8,"name":"ironman"},
{"strength":1714,"day":"2016-05-09T05:00:00.000Z","rescue":3,"name":"Antman"}]
```

I want to use the whole 7 days to build my x-axis so I'm doing something like this :

```
 dataset.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.key);
});
```

Ok great I now have my data formatted for the x-axis of the bar chart more or less. Now let's say that for the y-axis-value I want the number of rescue by day, I need to do something like this :

```
 dataset = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.date; })
  .rollup(function(d) { return d.length; })
  .entries(dataset);
```

But the thing is that after I applied this nested function my date data are in a string again and if I use parseDate function a second time, I have a "t.slice error".

So at the end I have a domain bind to d.date but when I'm biding my nested data to my svg selection I can't use d.date because my date data aren't formatted. And If I'm doing the dataset.forEach after my nested selection I can't have my x-axis bind for each day since all the 7 day won't appear in my returned data.

Hope you get my point and have a solution. thanks.

update : I've ended-up calling my dataset twice with two d3.json function not very clean but...

Comment: Not sure this is the cause of the problem, but if you want to aggregate by day, the function passed to nest.key needs to return d.date instead of d.rescue.

Comment: Yet like you say this is not the cause of the problem but think :) my post will be more clear ;)

Comment: Can you post your parseDate function?

Comment: yep. `var parseDate = d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse`

Comment: The problem is in how you're using `parseDate`. It returns a Date instance, so you need to retrieve the day by calling `Date.getDay()`. I've got your code running [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rafaveguim/qt2hfaf5/).

Comment: Note that parseDate won't be able to parse "monday" and "wednesday", so the entries under these values are grouped within "null".

Comment: ok thank. However I'm not sure it's a solution for me since I need to retrieve the date in my dataset. If I look at your data in the console log there is no date. Could you explain me in more details what your doing here `dataset.forEach(function(d) {
  var date = parseDate(d.day);
  d.date = date ? date.getDay() + 1 : null;
});` I don't understand...

Comment: If you don't call rollup then you will find the data objects as the leaves of your tree and you will still be able to easily get the number elements for each date. See the new code on jsfiddle. If that's not you're looking for, let us know the structure you want, e.g., day -> hour -> object

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot. you're right, I have to find a way to explain my self better. Let me work on this !